# How does Mathematica choose which function definition to use?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I was wondering what the process of matching function arguments arguments against different function definitions actually looks like for Mathematica.

(Just to be clear, I'm **not** simply looking for an answer to the question "given two or more definitions for a head `f`, which will Mathematica choose?"—I'm interested in how the process itself takes place.)

So, for example, if I define a function `f[x : _Integer] := 3`, and then evaluate `f[5] // Trace` or `f[5] // TracePrint`, I never see Mathematica attempt to `MatchQ` `5` against `_Integer`. Likewise for any pattern.

For what I'm guessing might be related reasons, I can't define

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x : patt] := 3;
patt = _Integer;
```

in that order, and have it behave as I'd expect; the result of `f[5]` is then just `f[5]`.

One exception seems to be patterns that involve function applications, e.g. `_?g`. Then `g` will show up in `Trace`. This makes me suspect that Mathematica does some sort of optimization when it can, and that the pattern matching typically takes place outside of the typical evaluation process...somehow.

(Note: I seem to remember seeing something at some point about a dispatch table being generated, so this might be a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find where. But even in that case, if it works like `Dispatch`, I don't quite understand the specifics of when it's applied, or how exactly the hash codes are used...)

**This question is motivated by the following concern:**

If I have something like `Table[f[i], {i,n}]`, will `i` be matched against the definitions for `f` each time `f` is evaluated? Or does Mathematica "figure out" that `i` will be an integer each time `f` is called on it, and "plan" to use the `_Integer` definition of `f` (if it exists)? The latter seems unlikely to me, especially given the difference in the following:

```
ClearAll[f,g]
f[x_Integer] := Null
f[x_String] := Null
f[x : {_Integer, _Integer}] := Null

g[x_] := Null

RepeatedTiming[Do[f[{i, i}];, {i, 2000000}]]
(* {1.58606, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[Do[g[{i, i}];, {i, 2000000}]]
(* {1.06015, Null} *)
```

I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241606/compile-time-patterns) based on this concern, but realized I should get a better understanding of what's actually going on first!

Comment: Function evaluation and more are described in Chapter 7 of _Power Programming with Mathematica_ by David B. Wagner.  It is freely available to StackExchangers via [(22724)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/142).

Comment: Great resource, thanks!